# Sed replacing number within curly braces with regex

Tags: regex, bash, perl, sed

I am trying to write a script to automate the process of generating multiple output files with different parameters. This requires replacing the number in curly braces after CONFIG.c_mm2s_burst_size and CONFIG.c_s2mm_burst_size in the following code statement.

```
  set_property -dict [ list CONFIG.c_include_mm2s {1} CONFIG.c_include_mm2s_dre {0} CONFIG.c_include_s2mm_dre {0} CONFIG.c_include_sg {0} CONFIG.c_m_axi_mm2s_data_width {32} CONFIG.c_m_axis_mm2s_tdata_width {32} CONFIG.c_micro_dma {0} CONFIG.c_mm2s_burst_size {2} CONFIG.c_s2mm_burst_size {2} CONFIG.c_sg_length_width {23}  ] $axi_dma_0
```

The code is in tcl. I tried variable substitution but it doesn't interpret correctly for something like 
`CONFIG.c_mm2s_burst_size {$var}`

So I think it shouldn't be difficult with sed and perl to replace the number in text. However, I have searched and tried all night without success.

I have tried:

```
sed -r 's/burst_size\>\s\{(\d+)\}/256/g'

sed -r 's/burst_size\s\{(\.+)\}/256/g'

sed -r 's/burst_size#\{(\d+)\}/256/g'

sed -r 's/burst_size\s\\{(\d+)\\}/256/g'
```

and many more, none of them works. I am using Ubuntu with GNU 4.2.2. Other one liner in other languages are welcomed to as long as I change the number systematically.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace the partcular number inside `{}` brackets which was preceded by the string `burst_size`, you could use the below sed command. sed won't support `\s` or `\d`. Instead of `\s` you could use the POSIX notation `[[:space:]]` and instead of `\d`, you could use `[0-9]`

```
sed 's/\(burst_size \+{\)[0-9]\+}/\1256}/g'
sed -r 's/(burst_size +\{)[0-9]+\}/\1256}/g'
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo 'CONFIG.c_mm2s_burst_size {2} CONFIG.c_s2mm_burst_size {2} CONFIG.c_sg_length_width {23}  ] $axi_dma_0' | sed 's/\(burst_size \+{\)[0-9]\+}/\1256}/g'
CONFIG.c_mm2s_burst_size {256} CONFIG.c_s2mm_burst_size {256} CONFIG.c_sg_length_width {23}  ] $axi_dma_0
$ echo 'CONFIG.c_mm2s_burst_size {2} CONFIG.c_s2mm_burst_size {2} CONFIG.c_sg_length_width {23}  ] $axi_dma_0' | sed -r 's/(burst_size +\{)[0-9]+\}/\1256}/g'
CONFIG.c_mm2s_burst_size {256} CONFIG.c_s2mm_burst_size {256} CONFIG.c_sg_length_width {23}  ] $axi_dma_0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the following Perl one-liner.

```
perl -pe 's/burst_size\s+{\K\d+/256/g'
```

Comment: Thank you hwnd, that works. But hope you don't mind if I accept the answer from the first responder.

Answer (score 1):

`\s` and `\d` and not recognized by sed

You can use either

```
sed -r 's/(burst_size )\{[0-9]+\}/\1{256}/g' input
```

or

```
sed -r 's/(burst_size[[:space:]])\{[[:digit:]]+\}/\1{256}/g' input
```